# Discord.js event updatePresence spamming

Tags: discord.js

I use the updatePresence event to log into the console when a user changes the status (online, dnd, etc.).
My problem is: If I change my status, the message is output 6 times in the console. 
Does anyone have a solution for the problem?

```
user is now online
user is now online
user is now online
user is now online
user is now online
user is now online
user is now online
```

Comment: please, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) article

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE: Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be because the user involved is in multiple [Guild](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild)s in common with the bot.

[presenceUpdate](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-presenceUpdate) is fire by each guilds.

Try to output the guild name to see if your user [Presence](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Presence) is from multiple guilds :

```js
client.on("presenceUpdate", (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
    if (oldPresence.status !== newPresence.status) {
        console.log(`${newPresence.user.tag} user is now ${newPresence.status} in guild ${newPresence.guild.name}`);
    }
});
```